# Cherokee rule for 301 redirect

Tags: cherokee

I am moving from Apache to Cherokee for some trials

I want to do the redirect in cherokee that i do for Apache:

# Redirect to the WWW canonical name
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.domain.com
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

But cant find any explanation on how this is done

any help apprectiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

Basically need to create another virtual host and set up the Default handler as a Redirect to the original host.

All the info is here
http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/modules_handlers_redir.html

What I wanted though was the ability to set up redirects without needing to recreate more virtual hosts, ie the way Apache allows me with Mod Rewrite inline

Hopefully they will create a handler for this soon:

i.e. Handler that allows you to choose that www.domain.com and domain.com go to the same roote and choice between the www.domain.com or .domain.com as the main one redirecting the other :) Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

If it's just one particular domain/sub-domain (or a reasonably small number of domains) you want to redirect, you don't need a separate virtual host (although you can go that route if you like). Here are the steps to redirect a naked domain like `domain.com` to its `www` sub-domain (`www.domain.com`) for cherokee v0.99.39:

1. On your cherokee-admin page (http://127.0.0.1:9090/), click the `Virtual Servers` link on the left nav, and then click the `Nickname` of the virtual server from which you want to redirect. You probably called this virtual server `domain.com` (or in its `Host Match` section, it has an entry for `*domain.com`); or it could just be the `default` virtual server.
2. Click the `Behavior` tab.
3. Click the `Add new rule` button.
4. Select `Header` for the `Rule Type`.
5. Select `Host` for the `Header`.
6. Enter `^domain.com` for the `Regular Expression` (and press tab to continue to the next screen). In this scenario we add `^` to the front of the domain from which we want to redirect so we just match the naked domain, and not any sub-domains.
7. Click the `Handler` tab.
8. Select `Redirection` for the `Handler`.
9. Enter `/(.*)` for the `Regular Expression`.
10. Enter `http://www.domain.com/$1` (again press tab to allow the ui to process your changes). The `$1` indicates where to put the content of the first capturing group from step 9's regular expression.
11. Click the `Save` button of the left nav.
12. Try it out! (Navigate to `http://domain.com/` and validate that you are redirected to `http://www.domain.com/` with a 301.)

Answer (score 3):

There is now a template for this in the web interface of Cherokee (in 1.0.8 at least):

1. Click `vServers` on the top navigation
2. Press the `New` button
3. Choose `Virtual Server Redirection` under `Tasks`
4. Start the wizard
5. Enter `example.com` for the `Origin Domain`
6. Enter `www.example.com` for the `Target Domain`
7. Hit the `Create` button

You can redirect multiple domains to the `Target Domain` also:

1. Edit the redirect virtual server (It should be the one with a document root of `/dev/null`)
2. Go to the `Host Match` tab
3. The `Method` should be set to `Wildcards` (you could choose `Regular Expressions` instead)
4. Press the `Add New` button to add more domain names

Answer (score 1):

The fix will be most likely released soon: http://bugs.cherokee-project.com/722